# ¿Cómo evitar el Trying to get property of non-object en array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Anteriormente hice una pregunta sobre el mismo tema, pero aun tengo problemas con algunas vistas. Tengo una consulta o un resultado que me arroja una API usando Guzzlehttp, la cual me arroja el siguiente array cuando imprimo con dd($user):

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#187 ▶}
]
```

Con esta información:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#187 ▼
    +"id": 555
    +"email": "test@test.co"
    +"company_id": null
    +"user_name": "Pruebas localHost"
    +"img": null
    +"user_position": null
    +"user_phone": null
    +"user_type": "US"
    +"user_validate": 0
    +"user_id_facebook": null
    +"user_conf_code": null
    +"created_at": "2017-07-28 14:05:01"
    +"updated_at": "2017-07-28 14:05:01"
  }
]
```

Con `print_r($user);`

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 555 [email] => test@test.co [company_id] => [user_name] => Pruebas localHost [img] => [user_position] => [user_phone] => [user_type] => US [user_validate] => 0 [user_id_facebook] => [user_conf_code] => [created_at] => 2017-07-28 14:05:01 [updated_at] => 2017-07-28 14:05:01 ) )
```

El problema es que cuando voy a llevar esta información a la vista no logro obtener los resultados `Trying to get property of non-object`. no se que estoy haciendo mal pero he usado varios métodos y siempre obtengo el mismo error. las formas que he usado: `foreach` `$user[0]['id']` `{{$user->id}}`

Este es el controlador que estoy usando:

```
public function login(Request $request){

    $client = new Client();

    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'email|required',
        'password' => 'min:3|max:100', 
    ]);

    $response = $client->post("http://localhost:8000/v1/login", [

        'headers' => ['foo' => 'bar'],
            'json' => [
                'email' => $request['email'],
                'password' => $request['password'],
            ]
    ]);

    $user = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

    dd($user);
    //return view('pages.home')->with('user', $user); --> No funciona
    //return view('pages.home', compact('user')); ---> No funciona
}
```

En la vista:

```
@foreach($user as $user)

     <li> {{$user->id}}" </li>

@endforeach
```

también intenté

```
<li> {{$user->id}}" </li>
```

¿Como debo pasar la variable de manera correcta a mis vistas?

Comment: Cualquiera de los códigos que tienes comentados devolviendo la vista deberían de funcionar. Puedes agregar el código de la vista?. Tambien prueba realizar `{{ dd($user) }}` en la vista.

Comment: -edité la respuesta, sin embargo como digo en la pregunta, he intentado con foreach, que me funcionó anteriormente, y otras formas como {{$user->id }}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas desempaquetar el objecto

```
$user = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents())[0];
```

El resultado de la funcion json_decode() devuelve un array de una posición;

Posteriormente puedes crear un arreglo vacío y asignarle en el indice 'user' el objeto $user

```
$data = [];
$data['user'] = $user

return view('pages.home', $data);
```

En tu vista ahora tendrás disponible al objeto $user

```
 <li> {{$user->id}}" </li>
```

Comment: Revisé el metodo y me funcionó. Gracias

Answer (score 3):

También lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

```
foreach ($users as $key => $user)
{
  $user['id'];
}
```

Espero sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

la verdad debiera de funcionar con $user[0]['id'] lo otro es que utilices print_r($user) para que mires que tipo de array o en que dimensión estamos trabajando.

```
print_r($user);
```

Así evidencias en **dimensión** debes de apuntar y te mostrara cada uno de la llaves

Comment: edité la respuesta con tu obsecración